# How to check if boxes are filled with information?

Tags: excel, vba

I think I have a syntax problem.
I want to check if every field is filled for next steps.
I have 15 more cells to check.

My code works, just the first line gives an error because of `and ("C24:C22")`.

```vb
For Each Zellen_auf_Inhalt_prüfen In Range("B7:J7") and ("C24:C22")

    If Zellen_auf_Inhalt_prüfen.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Bitte alle Zellen ausfüllen."
        GoTo MacroEnde
    End If

Next Zellen_auf_Inhalt_prüfen
```

"Zellen auf inhalt prüfen" means, to check if there is anything in cells.

Comment: `Range("B7:J7,C22:C24")`

Comment: thank you, i feel so dumb now... i hang on this for an hour. gracias

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the union statement:

```
For Each Zellen_auf_Inhalt_prüfen In Union(Range("B7:J7"), Range("C24:C22"))
```